# Вложенные внутренние

Tags: java

> Java позволяет создавать одни классы внутри других: Именно такие
>   классы и называют вложенными.
>
> Если один класс объявить внутри другого, то такой класс называется
>   внутренним.

Вот это я прочитал на сайте (платный курс), в одной статье написано одно, а в другой другое, где правильней?

Comment: Оба утверждения корректны - это раз. Второе, если сайт платный, то пусть вам разжуют, а то что это, деньги платите, а информацию искать на стороне приходится

Comment: @Dred да как раз таки я там 2 ошибки нашел и уже отправил им, жду ответа, в примере написано что там мол конструктор, а написано class Car {, а не public Car() { допустим

Comment: Вот, посмотрите ссылку из комментария. Скорее всего это то, что вы ищете)